# Error Log Configuration confusion

Tags: apache, logging, nginx

Someone said that Apache Shows 503 details in the error log, but my nginx logs 503 errors in access.log.

Are 503 errors supposed to be logged as access or error?

Comment: `access_log` is logging info about request/response. `error_log` is about logging nginx's internals. E.g. for error 502 you'll see one string in access log that means nginx send 502 error page to client and bunch of info in error log how nginx tried to connect to upstream and failed.

Answer (score 1):

Apache logs 503 errors in the access log, just like nginx.

There's an easy way to test it. Just add this rewrite rule to a temporary website, monitor the access log, and you'll see the 503 request.

`RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]`

Actually, 503 errors mean something wrong happened between the server handling the request and the final destination of the request.

Typical scenarios are load balancing or proxy servers. In case you use Apache or nginx to proxy requests to another server and this second server isn't available, a 503 could happen, but there's no error per se on the Apache or nginx side, hence the error being logged as an access.